# Data from a txt file and into 2d array but shows arrayindexoutofbound error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

When I run this:

```
readData("data.txt")
```

I want to use this data for binary classification using SVM. Each data has a class label in the last column, so I put these in another array named `type`, but when I run, it prints all the value, but it then shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at practice.A.readData(A.java:48)
    at practice.A.main(A.java:86)
```

i want to know what cause these exception

```
public class A {
    static double [][] train,testdata,attributes;
    static int row,col,x;;
    static double [] type;
    static void readData(String fileName)  {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();
        for(row=1;reader.readLine()!= null;row++) {}    
        col= 1;
        for (int i=0;i<line.length();i++) {
            if(line.charAt(i)==',') 
                col++;
        }
        System.out.println(row);
        System.out.println(col);
         x=col-1;
        if(reader!=null) reader.close();
        attributes = new double[row][x];
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String []words=new String[col];
        type =new double[row];
        for(int i=0; i<row;i++) {
            List<String> ob;
            ArrayList<String> w=new ArrayList<>();
            line = reader.readLine();
            words =line.split(",");
            if(!words[x].isEmpty())
                type[i]=Double.parseDouble(words[x]);
            ob=Arrays.asList(words);
            w.addAll(ob);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
            w.remove(x);
            String [] new_words=new String[w.size()];
            new_words=w.toArray(new_words);
            for(int j=0;j<new_words.length;j++) {
                if(!new_words[j].isEmpty()){
                    attributes[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(new_words[j]);
                    System.out.print(attributes[i][j]+" ");
                }
            }
            w.clear();;
            System.out.println(type[i]);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Comment: it will be helpful if u tell what causes these exception